# Advice about formula for exact differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When I realize that I have exact differential equation I know that is good to use specific formula. 
But this formula has two forms.
Can you tell me when I must use first and when second form?

Picture of formula is here:

[Formula](http://www.deviantpics.com/images/2016/06/24/Screen%20Shot%2006-24-16%20at%2009.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula on the left hand side of your picture should be used when $P(x,y)$ can be easily integrated with respect to $x $ and the formula to the right hand side should be used when $Q(x,y)$ can be easily integrated with respect to $y$.